# Comparing equality of two numbers using JavaScript Number() function

Tags: javascript

When I try to compare two numbers using **JavaScript** `Number()` function, it returns `false` value for equal numbers. However, the grater-than(">") and less-than("<") operations return `true`.

```
var fn = 20;
var sn = 20;

alert(new Number(fn) === new Number(sn));
```

This alert returns a `false` value. Why is this not returns `true`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> `new Number()` will return `object` not `Number` and you can not compare objects like this. `alert({}==={});` will return `false` too.

Remove `new` as you do not need to create new instance of `Number` to compare values.

```js
var fn = 20;
var sn = 20;

alert(Number(fn) === Number(sn));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using floating numbers and if they are computed ones. Below will be a slightly more reliable way.

```
console.log(Number(0.1 + 0.2) == Number(0.3)); // This will return false.
```

To reliably/almost reliably do this you can use something like this.

```
const areTheNumbersAlmostEqual = (num1, num2) => {
    return Math.abs( num1 - num2 ) < Number.EPSILON;
}
console.log(areTheNumbersAlmostEqual(0.1 + 0.2, 0.3));
```